# Uniqueness of differential equation (generalisation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

What are the necessary conditions for the existance of a solution to a differential equation?
What conditions must be added in order to have a unique solution?
$$$$
I know $f(y_0)\neq0$ is needed to rule out $f(y)=0$ (for uniqueness) but I've also heard that a function must be Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: Are you talking about the initial value problem $y' = f(y)$, $y(0) = y_0$?  Continuity of $f$ on a neighbourhood of $y_0$ is **sufficient** for local existence, and local Lipschitz continuity is **sufficient** for uniqueness, but neither is necessary.

Comment: Standard results establish sufficient conditions for (typically local) existence and uniqueness of solution. However, when you define what you accept as a solution to a differential equation, this can be understood as a set of necessary conditions. Your second sentence makes me wonder if you are thinking of a particular type of differential equation...

Comment: yeah that's what I meant. But is local Lipschitz continuity of $f(y)$ not sufficient to have a solution?

Comment: not a type in particular but here are some differential equations I saw: $$y'(t)+a(t)y(t)=b(t)$$ $$y'=f(t)$$ $$y''(t)+p(t)y'(t)+q(t)y(y)=0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the differential equation of the first order IVP

$y'=f(x,y)$ with  $y(x_0) = y_0$ . .  . . .$(1)$

> **Existence theorem:** Suppose that $f(x, y)$ is continuous function in some region $$R=\{(x,y):|x-x_0|\le a,|y-y_0|\le b\},  (a,b\gt0)$$
>   Since $f$ is continuous in a closed and bounded domain, it is necessarily bounded in $R$,
>   i.e., there exists $k > 0$ such that $|f(x, y)| ≤ k$, $∀(x, y) ∈ R$. Then the IVP $(1)$ has at least one solution $y = y(x)$ defined in the interval $|x − x_0| ≤ α$ where $\alpha=min\{a,\frac{b}{k}\}$.

${}$

> **Uniquness theorem:** Suppose that $f$ and $\frac{∂f}{∂y}$ are continuous function
>   in $R$ (defined in the existence theorem). Hence, both the $f$ and $\frac{∂f}{∂y}$ are bounded in $R$, i.e.,
>
> $1.$  $|f(x, y)| ≤ K$, $∀(x, y) ∈ R$
>
> $2.$ $|\frac{∂f}{∂y}|≤ M$, $∀(x, y) ∈ R$
>
> Then the IVP $(1)$ has at most one solution $y = y(x)$ defined in the interval $|x − x_0| ≤ α$ where $\alpha=min\{a,\frac{b}{k}\}$.
>
> Combining with existence thereom, the IVP $(1)$ has unique solution $y = y(x)$ defined
>   in the interval $|x − x_0| ≤ α$.

${}$

---

**Note:** Condition $|\frac{∂f}{∂y}|≤ M$, $∀(x, y) ∈ R$ can be replaced by a weaker condition which is known as **Lipschitz condition**. Thus, instead of continuity of $\frac{∂f}{∂y}$, we require

$|f(x, y_1) − f(x, y_2)| ≤ L|y_1 − y_2|$  $ ∀(x, y_i) ∈ R$.

If $\frac{∂f}{∂y}$ exists and is bounded, then it necessarily satisfies Lipschitz condition. On the other hand, a function $f(x, y)$ may be Lipschitz continuous but $\frac{∂f}{∂y}$ may not exists.

**For example** $f(x, y) = x^2|y|$, $|x| ≤ 1$, $|y| ≤ 1$ is Lipschitz continuous in $y$ but $\frac{∂f}{∂y}$ does not exist at $(x, 0)$.

${}$

---

---

Consider the second order initial value problem

$y''(t)+p(t)y'(t)+q(t)y=g(t)$, with $y(t_0) = y_0, y′(t_0) = y^′_0.$ .  . . . . $(2)$

> If the functions $p(t)$, $q(t)$, and $g(t)$ are continuous on the interval $I: α < t < β$
>   containing the point $t = t_0$. Then there exists a unique solution $y = φ(t)$ of the
>   problem $(2)$, and that this solution exists throughout the interval $I$.

That is, the theorem guarantees that the given initial value problem $(2)$ will
always have (existence of) exactly one (uniqueness) twice-differentiable
solution, on any interval containing $t_0$ as long as all three functions $p(t), q(t),$
and $g(t)$ are continuous on the same interval. Conversely, neither existence
nor uniqueness of a solution is guaranteed at a discontinuity of $p(t), q(t),$ or
$g(t)$.

${}$

---

For more information and examples you can find the following :

$1.$ 'Differential Equations Theory, Technique and Practice' by G. F. Simmons & S. G. Krantz (McGraw Hill Higher Education)

$2.$ "Differential Equations" by Shepley L. Ross

$3.$ http://home.iitk.ac.in/~sghorai/TEACHING/MTH203/ode5.pdf

$4.$ http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~y1zhao/2013UCSDFallQuarterMath20D/Files/Section3.2.pdf

$5.$ http://www.ltcconline.net/greenl/courses/204/ConstantCoeff/uniquenessExistence.htm

Comment: with the Lipschitz condition is it a problem for uniqueness if $\frac{∂f}{∂y}$ does not exist?

Comment: If $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ does not exist or not bounded in the neighborhood of a point, say $x=a$, then $f$ does not satisfies Lipschitz condition in the neighborhood of $x=a$. So we can't apply this method (called "Picard's Existence and Uniqueness theorem") to obtain an uniqueness conclusion. Also we must not conclude that Uniqueness is impossible simply because   Lipschitz condition is not satisfied.

Comment: but you said "$f(x,y)$  may be Lipschitz continuous but $\frac{∂f}{∂y}$ may not exists"

Comment: Please read the previous line and understand the meaning of that line. The line is "If $\frac{∂f}{∂y}$ exists and is bounded, then it necessarily satisfies Lipschitz condition." Here the word "necessarily satisfies" is most important. This condition is necessary but not sufficient.

Comment: There are functions that are  Lipschitz continuous but $\frac{∂f}{∂y}$ does not exist. I give here a counter example for such case.

Comment: okay so if I want to replace condition $|\frac{∂f}{∂y}|≤ M$ $∀(x, y) ∈ R$ by the Lipschitz condition I must keep the existance of $\frac{∂f}{∂y}$

Comment: what about this $f(y_0)\neq0$ constaint on the initial conditions? Is it any helpful to prove uniqueness or to rule it out?

Comment: Yes, you must keep the existence of $\frac{∂f}{∂y}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94024/discussion-between-nmasanta-and-maxime).