# Intuition behind One-sided Lipschitz

Tags: continuity, intuition, lipschitz-functions

In my current lecture *Numerical Analysis of Ordinary Differential Equations* we introduced the concept of One-sided Lipschitz functions.

> A function $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^d$ satisfies a **one-sided Lipschitz condition** on it's domain $D \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{C}^d$ if there exists $C \in \mathbb{R}$, such that the inequality
>
> $$\Re((f(t,x) - f(t,y))^t(x-y)) \leq C|x-y|^2$$
>
> holds for all $(t,x),(t,y) \in D$.

I always visualised the Lipschitz condition using this [cone-intuition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity#/media/File:Lipschitz_Visualisierung.gif), but can't seem to find an analogue for the one-sided Lipschitz condition. Is there a visual interpretation of the one-sided version that, for example helps me understand why $f(x) = e^{-x}$ satisfies a one-sided Lipschitz condition?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you have already mentioned, Lipschitz condition is sometimes illustrated by a [cone condition](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/58/Lipschitz_Visualisierung.gif):

[image]

Note that the Lipschitz constant $C$ is related to the (white) cone angle, i.e. if $\theta$ is the angle between two generating lines of the cone (which we call $L_1$ and $L_2$) then
$$C=\cot\frac{\theta}2$$
The key to understand or visualize one-sided Lipschitz condition is the $\frac{\theta}2$ term. If a function is not Lipschitz at all, then there is no $C$ or in other words, $C$ tends to infinity and thus $\frac{\theta}2$ or $\theta$ are zero. This means that the cone vanishes.

Let $\alpha_1$ be the angle between $L_1$ and the vertical line. Also let $\alpha_2=\theta-\alpha_1$. For a Lipschits function, these are both equal to $\frac{\theta}2$. But if a function is Lipschitz only in one direction, it would mean either of $\cot\alpha_1$ or $\cot\alpha_2$ is undefined. So either $\alpha_1=0$ or $\alpha_2=0$. In other words, the cone is ***oblique***.

For example, $f(x)=e^{-x}$ is one-sided Lipschitz with $C=0$. You can easily verify that in this case $\alpha_1=90^\circ$ and $\alpha_2=0$.

[image: exp-x]

**Edit**: How to mathematically formulate this property?

For real functions of a single variable, the relationship between the intuition and mathematical formulation is straightforward. In this case, if a function is Lipschitz on a domain $D\subset\mathbb R$ then $$|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\le C|x_1-x_2|,\quad \{x_1,x_2\}\subset D$$
And if it is one-sided Lipschitz, there would be *no absolute values* in this inequality. For example, if $f$ is Lipschitz on the right side then for every real values of $x_1$ and $x_2$ on its domain, there is $C\ge 0$ such that
$$f(x_2)-f(x_1)\le C(x_2-x_1)$$
which can be re-written as
$$\left(f(x_2)-f(x_1)\right)(x_2-x_1)\le C|x_2-x_1|^2\tag{*}$$
Now for multi-variable complex functions, the $(*)$ condition can be generalized to the form you mentioned:
$$\Re\{\left(f(x_2) - f(x_1)\right)^T(x_2-x_1)\} \leq C||x_2-x_1||^2$$

Comment: Can this intuition also explain requiring the opposite inequality, such as [here](https://simons.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/docs/17890/gmos21-bckatycraigslides.pdf) (bottom of slide 4)?

Comment: @Ramanujan unfortunately, I didn't get what you mean. What I can tell about the slides is, they talk about uniqueness of the solution of some PDEs which has something to do with Lipschitz condition. Sometimes this condition can be relaxed to its one-sided form. I am not an expert in PDEs and can't comment further. You may refer to some other questions such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3235869/301977)

Comment: If I understood your post correctly, you explain why a one-sided Lipschitz condition has to look as the OP describes. I was wondering if a similar argument can also be applied to motivate why a one-sided Lipschitz condition might take the form on those slides.

Comment: I do not see the equivalence between $(\star)$ and the previous inequality. If $x_2 < x_1$, then $(\star)$ does not imply the previous inequality, right? What am I missing here?

Comment: @Kurban note that it's a **one-sided** Lipschitz function. It's inherently assumed that $x_2>x_1$

Answer (score 1):

**Simple, but rough intuition:**

While the original Lipschitz constraints both the rate of decrease and rate of increase of a function at any point in the domain,

The one sided Lipschitz constraint asks only for a bound on the rate of increase or on the rate of decrease for a function.

For example, consider the function $e^{-x}+x$.

By making $x\to -\infty$, we can make $\frac{d[e^{-x}+x]}{d(-x)} = e^{-x}-1$ as negative as we want. That is, the function can be decreasing as fast as we want.

But, we have a strict upper bound of 1 on the rate of increase of this function. The function can never increase any faster at any point in its domain.

I think this maybe a nice complement to @polfosol 's answer.