# One sided Lipschitz condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

i would like to give an example of one sided condition of Lipschitz, but its difficult to me and i can't think of any. Besides, there is almost nothing on the internet. Does anyone have an example?

My definition of one-sided Lipschitz is given in the following theorem that you can find in R.P.  Agarwal, V.  Lakshmikantham (1993) Uniqueness  and  nonuniqueness  criteria  for  ordinary  differential equations, World Scientific:

Let $f(x, y)$ be continuous in $$\bar{S}_{+}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}: x_{0}\leq x\leq x_{0}+a,  \ y_{0}-b\leq y\leq y_{0}+ b\}$$
and for all $(x, y), (x, \bar{y})$ in $\bar{S}_{+}$ with $\bar{y}\geq y$ it satisfies one - sided Lipschitz
condition $$ f(x,\bar{y})-f(x,y)\leq L(\bar{y}-y)$$
Then, the initial value problem has at most one solution in $[x_0 , x_0 + a]$.

Comment: I don't know what exactly is the definition of one-sided Lipschitz, but I guess every Lipschitz function is one-sided Lipschitz?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuition behind One-sided Lipschitz](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3281656/intuition-behind-one-sided-lipschitz)

Comment: Has the function to be continuous? If not, take any function with jumps that is left-side continuous and Lipschitz where it is continuous. I think the Daubechies D4 wavelet could be an example, it is fractal with vertical tangents to one side and horizontal ones to the other.

Comment: Depends on your definition of one-sided Lipschitz. In a Hilbert spaces $H$ its common to call $f:H \to H$ one-sided Lipschitz if $\langle f(x)-f(y),x-y \rangle \le L \|x-y\|^2$ for some constant $L \in \mathbb{R}$. For example if $H=\mathbb{R}$ then each decreasing function is one-sided Lipschitz with constant $L=0$.

Comment: Yes! The function has to be continuous. I just wrote the definition in the body of the question. Sorry, it's the first time I write here and I don't know how to use it very well!! I'm doing my final degree project about uniqueness of solution of differential equations, and i would like to give an example of that condition using the definition.

Comment: What is $t$ in your definition above?

Comment: I made a mistake when typing, sorry :(

Comment: You should make clear what type of example you are looking for. For example, if you want an example where Picard-Lindelöf cannot be applied take $f:[0,1] \times [-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x,y)=-xy^{1/3}$. Here $f$ is continuous, one-sided Lipschitz with $L=0$ and not Lipschitz (w.r.t. $y$).

Comment: Well, I was thinking of an example like the one you gave. But my doubt is that I don't know how to prove the condition. In your example, how do you know the constant is $L=0$?

Comment: If $z \ge y$ then $f(x,z)-f(x,y)=x(y^{1/3}-z^{1/3}) \le 0=0(z-y)$ as $t \mapsto t^{1/3}$ is increasing and $x \ge 0$.