# Why don't linear differential equations have any singular solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singular-solution

A function $\phi(x)$ is called the singular solution of the differential equation $F(x,y,y')=0,$ if uniqueness of solution is violated at each point of the domain of the equation. Geometrically this means that more than one integral curve with the common tangent line passes through each point $(x_0,y_0).$

Sometimes the weaker definition of the singular solution is used, when the uniqueness of solution of differential equation may be violated only at some points.

In many books, online videos, notes available in the Google, the differential equations $F(x,y,y')=0$ used to find the singular solution are taken as non-linear differential equation.

> Is it possible that this differential equation $F(x,y,y')=0$ be  linear.

I think the question is now more clear than the previous version.

Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: And why should they have singular solutions? For linear equations you can easily prove the existence and uniqueness of globally defined smooth solutions (given enough regularity of the rhs) and, furthermore, in many cases you can explicitly obtain them in closed form.

Comment: So you want to inform that singular solution is available for those differential equation for which we have a confusion of the existence and uniqueness of its solution.

Comment: Not entirely. An equation $F(x,y,y')=0$ is an implicit ODE if the function $F(x,y,p)$ is solvable for $p$. By the implicit function theorem this is possible outside the singular set $\partial_pF(x,y,p)=0$. The set of equations $F(x,y,y')=0, \partial_pF(x,y,p)=0$ defines a curve where it is regular. Under specific conditions this curve itself solves the ODE, like in the Clairaut equation, so that it is the singular solution. But in general that is not the case.

Comment: @nmasanta That is not what I meant. Singular solution is just a name for a particular solution that does not fit in the general rule/formula. If you obtain a formula that describes all the solutions, there are no singular solutions...

Comment: This question is too vague, and this is the reason why there are conflicting comments. We cannot argue on words alone; we need some **formulas**. What kind of linear differential equation are you considering? What is the definition of *solution*?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Consider any kind of linear differential equation.

Comment: I think you need formulas. Without them I am not answering this, it is too vague.

Comment: No, I only need the explanation of my question, nothing else. I informed previously that I have enough knowledge about "what is solution? what is general solution? what is singular solution ? and how to find those."